# Multiple UIViewControllers in one storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitableview

I am working on an app that deals with a book. The app uses tables views as the navigation. There is easily over 500 chapters all together. I was going to make a single UIViewController for each chapter. As you can guess that is causing my computer to run out of memory(I have 8GBs). Is there a way to iterate this process? Each UIViewController has the exact same layout.

Thank you for your time,

PJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one UIViewController  for each chapter is crazy

Use UIScrollview with NSMMUtable array with UIView inside of it with your content

Something like that:

Storyboard:
UIViewcontroller contains UIScrollView;

Code:
Bind NSMutableArray with your content (custom objects or text depending of the requirement);
Display the content for each element in a UIView;
Add UIView to the UIScrollView;

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response. That is a great idea and I am going to try and implement it. Thank you again.